# Gerrit HA plugin, issue with new users

Tags: lucene, synchronization, gerrit, high-availability

I'm using Gerrit 2.13.5 and there are 2 instances in Multi-Master system. I'm using `gerrit high-availability plugin` for syncing caches, events and indexes. Everything works fine exclude one strange thing:
when I create new user, I can login only on one Gerrit server, in another one I receive the following error:

> [2017-08-04 09:38:31,391] [HTTP-57] ERROR
>   com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet : Unable to
>   authenticate user "user_test"
>   com.google.gerrit.server.account.AccountException: Cannot assign
>   external ID "gerrit:user_test" to account 1000256; external ID already
>   in use.

Smth like HA plugin doesn't synchronize users in indexes on both Gerrit.

Please note that all other actions (changes in Change requests, in projects) syncs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was fault of Gerrit version 2.13.5. High-availability plugin does not support user accounts replications for this version. So you have to update gerrit to newer version or write custom `sh` script for manual indexing new users' accounts